# Writing to another text file and more?

Tags: python, file-io

I am trying to create a code which writes text to another file. This is my code so far.

```
import random
import time
a = open("settings.txt", "r")
b = open("settings.txt", "a")
adding = input("Enter Name: ")
with open("settings.txt", "a") as f:
     f.write('\n'.join(str(i) for i in adding))
data = a.readlines()
print (data)
time.sleep(10)
```

When its added to the txt file it comes up like this:
Blah 1
Blah 2
Blah 3
J
o
h
nJohn

How do I get it to be horizontal like 'Blah 1' and 'Blah 2'?
Also when I print the data from the notepad on python it has '/n' after each line e.g. 'Blah 1/n'
Could someone please help me spot where I might have gone wrong?

Comment: What file are you trying to read from and write to?

Comment: a notepad text file. the text that i enter comes out all on different lines. for example i type john. then that will be on the notepad file with 1 letter on each line.

Comment: Which files in your code?  Its very unclear.  You seem to open several files and then not do anything with them.  Are you trying to write to settings.txt, read settings.txt, etc?  What is adding supposed to be?

Comment: My problem is when i write to the settings.txt

Comment: Your problem isn't clear. You want to print it horizontally to the file? You need to provide us with whats in the file and what is the expected output.

Comment: Also what operating system and version of python?

Comment: I am very sorry tis is my first time using this website

Comment: By horizontally i mean the whole word 'John' all on one line. Not each letter on one line.

Comment: You just need f.write(adding) instead. I'll write up a more in-depth result in a bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import random
import time
adding = input("Enter Name: ")
with open("settings.txt", "a+") as f:
    f.write('\n'.join(i for i in adding.split() if len(adding.split(" "))>1 else adding))
    data = a.readlines()
for line in data:
    print (line)
time.sleep(10)
```

Try this. This prompts the user for input, splits that input across whitespace (so if I enter "Adam D. Smith" it returns ["Adam","D","Smith"]) if there's more than one word, then sends each one to the textfile "settings.txt", appending it to the end one line at a time, then reading the file back via data, reading it one line at a time.

```
>>>Enter Name: Adam D Smith
Adam
D
Smith
```

Is this the expected behavior?

Comment: For me it is saying a ERROR INVALID SYNTAX. i am using python 3.3.2. Let me try make this a bit more clearer. I want to be able to enter a word into python which will then write to a text file(settings.txt). When i enter John it comes up as each letter on a different line. I want it to come up all on one line. i hope that makes it a bit more clearer.

Comment: Put the traceback for the error message into your question and reply to my comment to let me know when you've edited. That shouldn't be happening. Did you copy/paste your code?

Comment: Invalid Syntax. It then highlights 'else' on Line 5

Comment: Since there's no "else" block in your code in the question, I can't help you. If you need a large text dump, please use www.pastebin.com and link it in your question. Please don't summarize, we need code not commentary :) Copy/Paste questions, re-write our answers. That's how you learn.

Comment: Thank You Very Much! Sorry for being so inefficient. This is my first time using this website.

Comment: No problem. I'm still waiting for that pastebin though.

Comment: Oh dont worry i had posted another question with more in depth detail showing each output and appearence before and after.